Logging time as SIC in part 91 and 135 ops
I am a holder of FAA and Argentinian Commercial ASEL,AMEL pilot licences. No type rating yet.
I am currently flying in Argentina for a company that owns several aircraft.  The two that concerns the questions are:
A B300 flew under part 91, and a B200 flew under part 135.
I am not yet in the annex as a designed pilot for the B200, being the sole manipulator at times, but I am already flying as SIC from the right seat.
For the B300 I am flying as SIC from the right seat, being the sole manipulator at times, there is no need to be in any annex since it's part 91.
The question is, how can I log this time
For the B200 (Part 135) as PIC under instruction on the empty legs? What about the legs with pax?
And For the B300 (Part 91)?

Are you flying under US rules or Argentinian rules?  It sounds like you are flying under U.S. rules.  Neither King Air variant requires a crew of two pilots.  You cannot log any time while the aircraft is operating under 135.  It is highly doubtful, you were a safety pilot under the Part 91 legs and so that time does not count either.

I am flying under Argentinian rules, but I was wondering how it would be in the US
